# Android Data Binding discards layout changes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, build.gradle, android-databinding

I am using Data Binding in an Android project.

After I added this snippet to build.gradle

`android {
    ....
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}`

as per this [guide](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html), the build process is discarding any layout changes I have made in axml files.

Any one knows what is the reason behind that?

**OS:** Windows 10.

**Android Studio version:** 2.3.1

**minSdkVersion**: 15

**targetSdkVersion**: 25

Comment: I don't think this is enough information - could you also provide the files, add exactly what you changed?

Comment: Thanks @Amylinn. Issue has been fixed by fixing all errors in the layout file. I figured out that if I have any errors in a layout file, the build process reverts it to the version of the last successful build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what's happening is you're being brought to the generated version of your layout file.  (I don't know why Android Studio sends you there, but it does sometimes.) If you look closely, you'll notice data binding code has been stripped out and the file path includes "generated" and "yourBuildType" (ex: "debug"). Any changes you make there won't persist once you build.

Try opening the layout yourself by file name and making edits there.

Comment: Thanks @lisa -wray, this was exactly what happened with me.